# Learnability of singleton in realizable case

Tags: machine-learning

I am required to show that the class of singletons $H_{sing}$ is learnable in the realizable case (without invoking the VC-dimension).

$H_{sing}$ is defined as
$H_{sing} := \{h \in \{0, 1\}^X : |\{x \in X : h(x) = 1\}| \le 1\}$

Also I need to prove if this class also learnable if $X = R$?

Can someone please help ?

Comment: What is $X$ in this case? is it finite? infinite? if its infinite, then which set is it?

Comment: Initially X is finite i.e. X has domain as N(Natural numbers) so it is finite.
Later or in the second part, we have X as infinite.

Comment: Natural numbers **aren't** finite. They are infinite.

Comment: Here we take finite Natural numbers for first part

Comment: The point of this exercise is for you to internalize the various definitions. This point would be completely lost if we solved this homework for you. I suggest starting by writing out all the relevant definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's see what a learning algorithm looks like. It takes as input samples $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_m,y_m)$, where $x_i \in X$ and $y_i \in \{0,1\}$, with the promise that $y_i = h(x_i)$ for some $h \in H_{\mathit{sing}}$. It should output some $h' \in H_{\mathit{sing}}$.

Second, let's see when a learning algorithm is successful, according to the definition of PAC learning. Here is what we need: for every $\epsilon,\delta>0$ we need there to be an $m = m(\epsilon,\delta)$ such that for every distribution $\mathcal{D}$ on $X$ and any $h \in H_{\mathit{sing}}$, if we feed the learning algorithm $m$ samples $(x_i,h(x_i))$, where $x_i \sim \mathcal{D}$, then with probability $1-\delta$ (over the choice of samples), the algorithm must output $h' \in H_{\mathit{sing}}$ such that $\Pr_{\mathcal{D}}[h' \neq h] \leq \epsilon$.

What can the learning algorithm do? It depends on what it sees. If $y_i = 1$ for some $i \in [m]$, then the learning algorithm can recover $h$. If $y_1 = \cdots = y_m = 0$, then the learning algorithm doesn't know anything about $h$, and so it might as well output $0$. This is the only reasonable learning algorithm. It remains to prove that for every $\epsilon,\delta$ you can find $m = m(\epsilon,\delta)$ for which the definition above is satisfied. This is your task.

Comment: Thanks! One small correction, shouldn't y_i ∈{0,1}?

Comment: Right, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am confused with one thing, if the y_1 =...= y_m = 0 then how can we be sure that PrD[h′≠h]≤ϵ?

Comment: You can’t be sure. That’s where $\delta$ comes in.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Can you guide why it fails in set of Real numbers ?

Comment: Does it? If so, then some step of the proof should fail.

Comment: I read somewhere that in singleton functions, negative hypothesis class gives 0 output, so I was curious

Answer (score 0):

The VC-dim seems to be finite for $X = N$ (thus is PAC-learnable). So what about for $X = R$? It feels like the VC-dim is still the same in that case, so can we assume it's still PAC-learnable right?